# Need starting advice on building my first DB admin and reporting app

Tags: database, user-experience

I want to build an app for database administration and reporting and presents a web interface UX.
App will need (at minimum) the following features:

1. Separate credentials for viewing reports, administrating the DB. Similar to "user" and "admin" roles.
2. Customizable (HTML?) layout for presenting live data in a digestible way (reports or live webpages that non-DBadmins, non-IT persons can understand).
3. Separate hosts (containers or VMs) for DB and application (both the app host and DB host will be on the same local network.
4. DB size of approximately 3000 unique records with approximately 50 fields (record attributes?) each.

The obstacles:

1. I have the data in Excel format currently; I presume it will need to be converted to SQL or some other DB format.
2. I have minimal DB administration experience (see further "Tools" below).
3. I have moderate HTML/CSS experience (see further "Tools" below).

Tools at my disposal:

1. MS SQL Server 2019 licensing (only if SQL is the best option).
2. MS Server 2019 Server licensing (again, if needed).
3. More than sufficient server and desktop hardware.
4. Time and patience: I'm not on a deadline and not afraid to learn something new. If it takes me the next year to learn the basics of all the components, I am willing to do so.

In a nutshell, I need advice on *which technologies* I need to begin training on.
I don't want build this app on obscure solutions. I want to use languages, interfaces, and operating systems that are fairly mainstream (e.g. ubuntu as opposed to openSUSE, SQL or MySQL as opposed to MariaDB, python as opposed to C#, etc.).

I'm not opposed to starting with a turnkey solution, so long as I can get into the nuts and bolts of it as I learn and want to customize things.

Thanks in advance for sating my curiosity, folks!

Started building HTML & CSS pages, but could not figure out how to display or manipulate excel data as a database.